Conditional types incorrectly infer union types
I am trying to write a function that conditionally infers the type of a generic input parameter that is a union. When I make the input type conditional, it throws an error showing that it infers the input must be an array of every value in the union instead of an array of any values from the union. Without the conditional typing, it correct infers that input can be an array of any value from the union:
type StringUnion = 'a' | 'b' | 'c'

const a: StringUnion[] = ['a']
console.log(a)

function basicTest<T>(props: { data: T[] }): T {
  return props.data[0];
}
const basicResult = basicTest({ data: a }) // No error

function conditionalTest<T>(props: { data: T extends string ? T[] : { inner: T[] } }): T {
  if ('inner' in props.data) {
    return props.data.inner[0];
  }
  return props.data[0];
}
const conditionalResult = conditionalTest({ data: a }) // Error
// Type 'StringUnion[]' is not assignable to type '"a"[] | "b"[] | "c"[]'.
//   Type 'StringUnion[]' is not assignable to type '"a"[]'.
//     Type 'StringUnion' is not assignable to type '"a"'.
//       Type '"b"' is not assignable to type '"a"'.ts(2322)
//
// test.ts(16, 34): The expected type comes from property 'data' which is declared here on type '{ data: "a"[] | "b"[] | "c"[]; }'

How can I avoid this type error when using a conditional type?

The problem is that the elements of the union type are being distributed for the conditional type, giving you "a"[] | "b"[] | "c"[] instead of StringUnion[]. You can prevent that by putting [] around each side of the extends condition ([T] extends [string]; scroll down a bit in the linked docs to see the documentation for that), like this: https://tsplay.dev/mLODvN

Here's that example again, updated to use the new name of the function from the edit: https://tsplay.dev/WKX5Kw
